# Replacing Image with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Initial stages of learning backbone.js (even Js infact).
The html page has 3 images. I want to replace the first image on clicking. I'm doing this as a learning process.  Please tell me what is wrong with the code or my logic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- HTML CODE -->

        <div align="center">
            <img src="pic1.jpg" id = "pic1" />
            <img src="pic2.jpg" id = "pic2" />
            <img src="pic3.jpg" id = "pic3" />
        </div>

  <!-- Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  <!-- Javascript code -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'body',
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },

            events: function(){
                "click #pic1": "replacePic1"
            },

            render: function(){
                console.log('view rendered. try clicking pic1');
                //this.$el.html(this.template({who: 'world!'}));
            },

            replacePic1: function(){
                alert("You can replace Pic1");
            }
        });

        var appView = new AppView();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A bit too many things wrong to explain in a reasonable amount of space -- have you tried following some javascript/backbone tutorials?

Comment: oh.. I haven't found many for beginners to follow. Well my goal is to build a Single Page Application, pretty quick (basically a python developer kicked into a JS project)

Comment: Most of the Backbone tutorials I've seen already expect a pretty solid understanding of Javascript. Maybe try http://www.codecademy.com/ first? For a person who's already a developer in another language the first lessons are a bit too simple, but they're quick enough to run through. After the first lesson you get to pick and choose the modules you want.

Comment: Cool. I shall do that right away. Thank you @fencliff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot you can improve but just to get things going try the following and remove the onClick that you have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- HTML CODE -->
    <div align="center">
        <img src="pic1.jpg" id = "pic1"/>
        <img src="pic2.jpg" id = "pic2" />
        <img src="pic3.jpg" id = "pic3" />
    </div>

    <!-- Libraries -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <!-- Javascript code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'body',
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },

            events: {
                "click #pic1": "replacePic1"
            },

            render: function(){
                console.log('view rendered. try clicking pic1');
                //this.$el.html(this.template({who: 'world!'}));
            },

            replacePic1: function(){
                $("#pic1").attr('src',"new/url.jpg");
            }
        });

        var appView = new AppView();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously this is not the way you want to go about things but might be worth trying out. A great backbone tutorial series I had found was a [Wine Cellar Tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/). Follow the whole series and you will learn a lot. Follow it up with the [Lessons Learned](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/) article and enjoy :)

Comment: replace el: $('#pic1') with el: 'body'

Comment: and comment the line: this.$el.html(this.template({who: 'world!'})); for now

Comment: not working still. PLease edit your post with the changes you make so that I can understand perfectly.

Comment: nope.. I will edit the original code with what I have currently.

Comment: Cool. It does. How can I change the pic into something else in the function?

Comment: I updated the code for you. Check the render function. Just change the URL to what you want. Note that this is not the best way to do things, it just gets your code working. I suggest you follow some tutorials to get things right

Comment: Thanks a lot @thearchitect .. I shall go thru some tutorials. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: If you have to upvote and mark it as the right answer, I'd appreciate it :)